# Is there a projection to draw north point and south point of a sphere like this and keep form of all circles on sphere?

Tags: graphics3d, regions

I see [this picture](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NorthPole.html)

[image]

and  draw this picture by [3dtools](https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools)

[image]

If I tried put two points $N$ and $S$ like the first picture, I get one cicrle

[image]

Is there a projection to draw north point and south point of sphere like this  [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NorthPole.html) and keep form of all circles on sphere

Comment: It is correct it is just from other view point.

Comment: You can use different view point `Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0, 0, 0}], PointSize[Large], Red, 
  Point[{0, 0, 1}]}, Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {0, -1, 0}]`.

Comment: If you use `Show[g1, rall, ViewPoint -> {0, -1, 0}]` for Syed's code, you get one a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

***Parameters***

```
angles = {-Pi/2, Pi/2};

{r1, r2}  = {1/4, 1/8};

displacement = -Pi/6;
```

***Coordinates***

```
l1 = Threaded[{r1, 1}] Transpose @ Through @ {Cos, Sin} @ (angles + Pi);
l2 = Threaded[{1, r2}] Transpose @ Through @ 
  {Cos, Sin} @ (angles + displacement);

pointcoords = Join[{{0, 0}}, l1, l2];
```

***Lines, Points***

```
points = Point /@ pointcoords;

dashedlines = Line /@ {l1, l2};
```

***Labels***

```
labels = Style[#, 16] & /@ {"O", "N", "S", "A", "B"};

offsets = {{1, -1}, {0, -3/2}, {0, 2}, {1, 3/2}, {-2, 3/2}};

texts = MapThread[Text] @ {labels, pointcoords, offsets};
```

***Circle segments***

```
trnsfrm = Circle[#, {1/r1, r2} #2, #3 + Pi/2] & @@ # &;

c1 = Circle[{0, 0}, {r1, 1}, angles];

dashedcirclesegments = {c1, trnsfrm @ c1};

solidcirclesegments = {#, trnsfrm @ #} & @ MapAt[# + Pi &, c1, {3}];
```

***All inside `Graphics`***

```
Graphics[{PointSize @ Large, points, texts,
  Circle[], solidcirclesegments, 
  Dashed, dashedcirclesegments, dashedlines}]
```

> picture at the top

Replace `displacement = -Pi/6` with `displacement = -Pi/12` to get

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"];

s1 = Sphere[];
ux = UnitVector[3, 1];
uy = UnitVector[3, 2];
uz = UnitVector[3, 3];
orig = {0, 0, 0};
r1 = RegionIntersection[s1, Hyperplane[ux, 0]];
r2 = RegionIntersection[s1, Hyperplane[uy, 0]];
r3 = RegionIntersection[s1, Hyperplane[uz, 0]];
xaxis = InfiniteLine[orig, ux];
yaxis = InfiniteLine[orig, uy];
zaxis = InfiniteLine[orig, uz];

rall = Region[#, Lighting -> {"Ambient", White}] & /@ {
    Style[s1, Opacity[0.05, Green]]
    , Style[r1, {Thin, Black}]
    , Style[r2, {Thin, Black}]
    , Style[r3, {Thin, Black}]
    };

g1 = Graphics3D[{
    {Dashed, xaxis, yaxis, zaxis}
    , Black, AbsolutePointSize[8]
    , Point@{orig, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 
       0, -1}}
    , Text[
     Style["O", Bold, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times", 
      16], {0, 0, 0} + {0.1, 0, 0.1}]
    , Text[
     Style["A", Bold, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times", 
      16], {1, 0, 0} + {0.1, 0, 0.1}]
    , Text[
     Style["B", Bold, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times", 
      16], {-1, 0, 0} + {-0.1, 0, 0.1}]
    , Text[
     Style["N", Bold, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times", 
      16], {0, 0, 1} + {0, 0.1, 0.1}]
    , Text[
     Style["S", Bold, Italic, FontFamily -> "Times", 
      16], {0, 0, -1} + {0, 0.1, -0.1}]
    }
   , Boxed -> False
   , Lighting -> {"Ambient", White}
   ];

Show[g1, rall]
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your code with `Show[g1, rall, ViewPoint -> {0, -1, 0}]`, I get one circle. It seems difficult for the view like this https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NorthPole.html

Comment: This is how 3D works. Please wait, and someone can perhaps write a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to get you started with the various options. It all depends on how much fidelity you want to those other pictures. You might even want to use 2D graphics and do your own projections.

```
Graphics3D[
  {{Opacity[.2], Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]}, 
   {Dashing[.04], Thick, Line[Append[0] /@ CirclePoints[100]]}, 
   {PointSize[Scaled[.05]], Red, Point[{0, 0, 1}], Point[{0, 0, -1}]}}, 
  Boxed -> False, 
  ViewPoint -> {0, -1, .1}, 
  ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"]
```

[image]